# Reusing multiplication logic for textboxes in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have  60 textboxes. Three in each row. For each of the twenty rows I am mutiplying the first two textboxes and storing the value in the third textbox.
I have created a simple logic for multiplying the values in two textboxes and storing the value in the third textbox.
Unfortunately this logic needs to be pasted twenty times. Is there a way to reuse the same logic for each row.
Any help will be much appreciated!

```
private void Multiplication()
    {
        int a;
        float b;
        if (BoxA.Text != "")
            {
            a= Convert.ToInt32(BoxA.Text);
            }
        else
            {
            a = 0;
            }
        if (BoxB.Text != "")
            {
            b = Convert.ToSingle(BoxB.Text);
            }
        else
            {
            b= 0;
            }

        float c= a* b;
        BoxC.Text = mult.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should share the logic using a shared method. Pass thee boxes, and perform the logic there:

```
private static void MultiplyBoxes(TextBox a, TextBox b, TextBox c) {
    if (!int.TryParse(a.Text, var out ia)) {
        ia = 0;
    }
    if (!int.TryParse(b.Text, var out ib)) {
        ib = 0;
    }
    c.Text = (ia*ib).ToString();
}
```

Now you can attach the same method for each row without having to copy-paste the actual logic.

**Note:** This is written in C# 7 syntax (the `var out` construct). If you use an earlier version, declare `int ia, ib` upfront, and use `out ia` and `out ib` in the method calls.